# Virtual-domain mail server installation on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, email-server, email

I'm trying to migrate my ancient FreeBSD box to a fresh new Ubuntu 9.04 install.

Problem is, to set up the email server on my FreeBSD box, there was the excellent qmailrocks guide, which is now very out of date, so I tried a little googling and found this guide for Ubuntu:
http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-ubuntu9.04

Unfortunately, I got so far into the guide and postfix stopped doing anything. It was listening on port 25, accepted the connection, but never sent the welcome message, and wouldn't respond to HELO/EHLO input. Basically, the install was *ahem* useless.

So I purged postfix, courier etc etc and googled again. Found old guides for debian which just plain do not apply anymore (I tried).

**My question is: what the hell should I be using for multi-domain email hosting on Ubuntu?**

I would really like to keep all my users and domains in MySQL, and an admin tool would be nice, but my no means essential (I have phpmyadmin and plenty of know-how to create an admin tool to insert a few records into the MySQL tables should I need to).

Help! :)

Comment: Thanks to bglick, I followed the guide he posted, it's a little out-of-date, but guided me enough to get the basic postfix+courier working together, I think I'll peruse daniels's link as that's a lot more thorough and should help me with amavisd and postgrey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also had this issue and i did a lot of Google-ing and found lots of tutorials but neither was what i was looking for.
Then i found a tutorial for setting up Postfix+Dovecot+MySQL which was perfect for what i wanted.
You can have everything up and running in 15min. The tutorial is for Debian but you can follow the same steps for Ubuntu.

http://wiki.vpslink.com/HOWTO:_ISP-style_Email_Server_with_Debian-Etch_and_Postfix_2.3

Comment: Followed this guide to add spamassassin, clamav, amavisd and postgrey. Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Just install Postfixadmin and be done with it.

Comment: http://postfixadmin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use postfix with postfixadmin. [This tutorial](http://knopix.wordpress.com/2008/01/16/postfixadmin-postgresql-courier-squirrelmail-on-debian-etch-howtotutorial/) should get you going in the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reinstall qmail again?

Comment: Because then you'd have a qmail server.  Don't get me wrong, I love daemontools and djbdns, and qmail raised the bar for MTAs at the time it was released, but it's not really a best-of-breed MTA these days.  The world of e-mail has changed (and not for the better).

Comment: @womble: I only ask because you implied that you were changing OSes and that forced a change of MTAs while changing one doesn't necessarily mandate changing the other.  I personally try to change only one big thing at a time.  I'm not really a qmail fanboy -- for instance, recently I thought about switching to postfix so I could do outgoing mail via smtpauth to my ISP via a smtproute and didn't feel like eating patchsoup, but whenever I install a new OS, I usually just carry forward my old email config because it (kinda) works and I'm lazy.